# Using anonymous pipes through Visual Studio

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, pipe

I'm using anonymous pipes to have 2 apps exchanging informations. App1 launch App2 and send/recv datas. Code is C++.

It works well in release.

Also, I have an option that let App1 launch App2 through Visual Studio debugger, with : devenv.exe /debug App2.exe

With Visual 2008 it worked like a charm, when Debugger opens, I can set my breakpoints, hit F5 and App2 starts, and I can debug it, and pipes are correctly communicating.

With Visual 2013 and 2015, it doesn't work anymore. When debugger starts App2, App2 cannot open the pipes handles, I have the error Invalid Handle.

Do you have an idea what's going on, if there is something to do on my side in pipe creation, or an option in Visual Studio?

Thanks

Gérald

Answer (score 0):

You should configure project launching: open context menu for Solution in `Solution Explorer` -> `Set Up Startup Projects`, select `Multiple Startup Projects` and configure the order at which your projects should be launched. Make sure that `Action` is set to `Start` so VS will launch them and attach debuger.

Comment: I don't see how this would solve my issue. I don't have problem to launch the App2 in debugger, just a problem with pipe that cannot be opened.

Comment: But have your tried using this approach? Launching application manually using devenv.exe commands seems to be quite unusual. They could've added some isolation level so launching program using another VS instance may effect application work somehow.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. In the question, App1 launches App2. This makes App2 a child process of App1. Launching App1 and App2 in parallel from Visual Studio makes them siblings. That is not what's intended.

Comment: @MSalters In the question App1 launches a new VS instance that's starts a separate debug session by launching App2. Notice that whether App2 is child or sibling is not really important because OP does not deal with standard streams, but if App2 is dwelling inside of different Debug session may have consequences (at least this is what I suspect).

Comment: That's right, App2 is a child of App1, if I'm not mistaken, that's how anonymous pipes can work, because App2 inheritates of App1 environment. But adding a layer with VS debugger launching App2 seems to somewhere breaks this inheritance. And I can't launch debugger in parallel, it's really App1 that is doing that, giving in command line some informations for App2, including handles of pipes that App2 will open.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to open it in Visual Studio 2017 you can set up your app to run on newer framework. I am not sure how to do it in earlier versions of Visual Studio

Comment: It's just pure C++, with a bit of WIN32 API to create pipes. And the goal is really to be able to debug the App2 at the very beginning.